# how to search integer using ilike in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I want to search row id = 123, if i have input field with 12 as input. Right now I have

```
where: {
        id: {
          [Op.iLike]: `%${req.body.gaugeId}%`,
        },
      },
```

This works if I am searching text fields, but it does not work for searching integer fields. I understand this is related to casting, but I could have find a way to implement this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured out the solution. I run into couple issues.

First I didn't understand how casting work. I need to cast on a sequelize column, and to access the column, you need to use `Model.column_name`.

Second Problem I run into was because I was casting to `string`, instead of `varchar`.

```
search(req, res) {
    return Gauge.findAll({
      where: sequelize.where(
        sequelize.cast(sequelize.col('Gauge.id'), 'varchar'),
        {[Op.iLike]: `%${req.body.gaugeId}%`}
      ),
    }).then(gauges => {
      res.status(200).send(gauges);
    });
  },
```

And if you want to use `sequelize.or`, you can do the following:

```
return Gauge.findAll({
        attributes: ['id', 'stationName'],
        where: {
          [Op.or]: [
            {stationName: {[Op.iLike]: `%${req.body.keyWord}%`}},
            sequelize.where(
              sequelize.cast(sequelize.col('Gauge.id'), 'varchar'),
              {[Op.iLike]: `%${req.body.keyWord}%`}
            ),
          ],
        },
      })
```

Here you can find more.
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3565

Comment: `"message": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR) LIKE '%1%'' at line 1",`

Comment: Also, the import method should be like this `import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';` or like this `import { Sequelize as sequelize } from 'sequelize';` unless it won't work in the latest versions of Sequalize JS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version you used but for

`"sequelize": "5.19.0"`

The following works:

```js
const { sequelize } = require('../database/models')
...
const results = await model.findAll({
 where: sequelize.where(sequelize.col('**column_name**'), 'LIKE', '%10%')
```

Which gives us:

[image]

and SQL:

```sql
WHERE `**column_name**` LIKE '%10%';
```

Regarding to documentation:

`public static where(attr: Object, comparator: Symbol, logic: string | Object): *`

The third arg should be a `Symbol`(e.g. `Op.like`), but I find `string` working as well.